# Starting text at newline after title of subsection

Tags: line-spacing, amsart

I am typing my document in `amsart` class.

I created a subsection with small title, and then wrote the paragraph of the subsection:

```
 \subsection*{Examples} 
 Consider a group of order 8.....
```

In the output, it shows title of subsection, and immediately after that, the paragraph starts. Then I inserted `\vskip1mm`:

```
\subsection*{Examples} 
\vskip1mm
Consider a group of order 8.....
```

But there was no effect of the command `\vskip1mm`.

**Question:** How can we leave the space between title of section and next paragraph?

Comment: `\subsection*{Examples}\leavevmode

Consider a group of order...` with an empty line between the subsection header and the text

Comment: @Christian: sorry, still this is not working.

Comment: Do you have the empty line after `\subsection*`? It works for me

Comment: @Christian: thanks for proper editing in question (I am not too familiar wit it, but I am getting now partially it. Thank you

Comment: I didn't see the line-spacing after title of subsection

Comment: There's no empty line in comments possible, that's why I wrote `...with an empty line` .. ;-) You don't need `\vskip` then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a precise choice of the class (which I agree with, by the way).

You can change one of the parameters in the definition of `\subsection`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{.3\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A section title}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{A subsection title}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course it works the same with `\subsection*`

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this I think.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{Examples}~\par
\vskip1mm
Consider a group of order 8.....
\end{document}
```